# What is a meaning of output of numpy's histogram function when density is True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, statistics, histogram

I don't understand the output of numpy's histogram function when density is True. When I do this:

```
hist = np.histogram(np.array([1,1, 2,3,4]), 4, density = False)
print("histogram: ", hist)
```

output is:

```
histogram:  (array([2, 1, 1, 1]), array([1.  , 1.75, 2.5 , 3.25, 4.  ]))
```

It is clear to me. I crated 4 intervals array([1.  , 1.75, 2.5 , 3.25, 4.  ]) and array([2, 1, 1, 1] are numbers of elements in each interval. But when I do it with density = True:

```
hist = np.histogram(np.array([1,1, 2,3,4]), 4, density = True)
print("histogram: ", hist)
```

result is:

```
histogram:  (array([0.53333333, 0.26666667, 0.26666667, 0.26666667]), array([1.  , 1.75, 2.5 , 3.25, 4.  ]))
```

I dint understand what are those numbers array([0.53333333, 0.26666667, 0.26666667, 0.26666667]). Documentation says that it is probability density function, but sum of PDF use be 1, so its not percentage of each element type. My question is, how those numbers are calculated? Could you explain on my given example?

Answer (score 2):

A clue is given in the second half of the documentation paragraph you read:

> density: bool, optional
>
> If False, the result will contain the number of
> samples in each bin. If True, the result is the value of the
> probability density function at the bin, normalized such that the
> integral over the range is 1. **Note that the sum of the histogram
> values will not be equal to 1 unless bins of unity width are chosen;
> it is not a probability mass function.**

The values you're seeing are the density value of the PDF at each bin. Those dont have a requirement of summing to 1 because they are not masses (as stated in the docs), but rather it is the *area under the PDF* that is equal to 1.

In your case, you can see that the area under the PDF, which is a function of bin height (density) and bin width, is equal to 1 by summing the product of height and width for each bin:

```
(0.53*0.75) + (0.27*0.75) + (0.27*0.75) + (0.27*0.75) = 1 (with some rounding error)
```

EDIT:

Regarding how those density values are calculated, you can see that in the [numpy source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7b0653cdd0d0a5ddcda061ee2eaf247f6303bc1e/numpy/lib/histograms.py#L904-L906):

```
if density:
    db = np.array(np.diff(bin_edges), float)
    return n/db/n.sum(), bin_edges
```

Where `n` is the array of histogram values, and `db` contains the bin widths

So, in your specific example, your first histogram value is 2, which converts to a density value of 0.53 in the following way:

```
2 / 0.75 / (2 + 1 + 1 + 1) = 0.53
```

Comment: what do you mean by "the area under the PDF that is equal to 1" ? All area under PDF function is equal to 1. An also why you multiply it to 0.75 (size of step between intervals)? And could you please break down the calculation of 0.53 for example?

Comment: the area under PDF is equal to 1, but when you simply sum those numbers (like you suggested in your question) you're not actually calculating the area. An area depends on both height and width, so you need to multiply each of those height values by the width, which is your bin width (or the size of step between intervals)

Comment: still don't get it) breaking down the calculation of 0.53 (for example) would be be great

Comment: @reredf Updated my answer to include how those density values are calculated